# How can I nest a count within a sql query

Tags: sql

I have the following two queries.

The first lists users and last login dates like this:

```
iUserNum  chDefaultLogin  dateLastLogin
--------  --------------  -------------
17        fred.bloggs     01/06/2011
23        john.doe        13/05/2011
```

using the following query

```
SELECT SDToken.iUserNum, chDefaultLogin, dateLastLogin
FROM SDUserScope JOIN SDToken ON SDUserScope.iUserNum = SDToken.iUserNum
```

The second one gives a count of the number of times a user has logged in (given the iUserNum user number) during the last 7 days using this query (in the example below I have given the iUserNum of 17):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SDToken 
   JOIN SDLogEntry ON SDLogEntry.chTokenSerialNum = SDToken.chSerialNum 
   JOIN SDUserScope ON SDToken.iUserNum = SDUserScope.iUserNum 
   JOIN SDLogMessage ON SDLogEntry.iMessageNum = SDLogMessage.iMessageNum 
   WHERE SDToken.iUserNum = 17 AND SDUserScope.iSiteNum = iMySite
     AND SDLogEntry.dtGMTDate > GMTDateNow - 7
```

What I want to do is join the two together, so I get the count for every user in the table, like this:

```
iUserNum  chDefaultLogin  dateLastLogin  loginCount
--------  --------------  -------------  ----------
17        fred.bloggs     01/06/2011     12
23        john.doe        13/05/2011     4
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm flying a bit blind here. This is on an application server (RSA) that has a basic query editor to enter queries - but I don't know what it is running behind the scenes.

Comment: Find that first coz RDBMS dont have same syntax for their SQL. pl-SQL and T-SQL and MySQl differ

Comment: I *think* it is based on MS SQL, possibly SQL Express. (Definitely not mySQL, if that helps!)

Comment: Apparently: "RSA ACE/Server maintains its data in a Progress relational database management
system (RDBMS)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to unify the queries and just add a Group by ?

```
SELECT  SDToken.iUserNum, 
        chDefaultLogin, 
        dateLastLogin,
        COUNT(*) AS loginCount
FROM SDUserScope 
    INNER JOIN SDToken 
        ON SDUserScope.iUserNum = SDToken.iUserNum
            INNER JOIN SDLogEntry 
                ON SDLogEntry.chTokenSerialNum = SDToken.chSerialNum 
                    INNER JOIN SDLogMessage 
                        ON SDLogEntry.iMessageNum = SDLogMessage.iMessageNum 
WHERE   SDToken.iUserNum = 17 
AND     SDUserScope.iSiteNum = iMySite 
AND     SDLogEntry.dtGMTDate > GMTDateNow - 7
GROUP BY    SDToken.iUserNum, 
            chDefaultLogin, 
            dateLastLogin
```

Comment: Think this is 99% there - however, I want the iUserNum in the second query (currently set to 17) to match up with the iUserNum of the user on that row. Is that possible here?

Comment: Wait a minute - am I just being numb? I guess I just need to remove the SDToken.iUserNum line from the WHERE clause...

Comment: Do you want your result table to include those users for whom the login count is zero?

Comment: @Ben: I think you are right, the filter on `iUserNum` should just be removed.

Comment: @Walter Mitty - yes I do. Do I need to change the join?

Answer (score 0):

2 subqueries joining on the username as common key    should do the job in MS Sql server /SYBASE it will lokk like below but any other RDBMS you can apply same logic using 2 subqueries...syntax might differ a little buit

```
Select A.SDToken.iUserNem, A.chDefaultLogin, A.dateLastLoginm,B.logincount
    FROM 
    (
        (SELECT SDToken.iUserNem, chDefaultLogin, dateLastLogin FROM SDUserScope JOIN SDToken ON SDUserScope.iUserNum = SDToken.iUserNum )A
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT COUNT(*)logincount,SDToken.iUserNem FROM SDToken    
         JOIN SDLogEntry ON SDLogEntry.chTokenSerialNum = SDToken.chSerialNum    
         JOIN SDUserScope ON SDToken.iUserNum = SDUserScope.iUserNum    
         JOIN SDLogMessage ON SDLogEntry.iMessageNum = SDLogMessage.iMessageNum    
         WHERE SDToken.iUserNum = 17 AND SDUserScope.iSiteNum = iMySite AND SDLogEntry.dtGMTDate > GMTDateNow - 7 
         GROUP BY SDToken.iUserNem)B
         ON A.iUserNem = B.iUserNem
    )
```